# How can I get SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I hope someone can shed some light on the SPLA methodology which allows you to get SQL Server 2008 R2 for ~$25/month if I understand correctly.

Do you have to do anything special in order to get SPLA access? I don't get the 'hosted' and 'service provider' definition - let's say I have a few web applications that I developed and I want to put those on a server and charge people monthly to use them, is that scenario SPLA covered? The users not being 'Windows'/'CAL' type users with windows authentication, but just regular ASP.NET authentication.

I really like SQL Server and I'd love to have a full Web Edition license for $25/mo - much better than the $3,000+ license when you buy it outright (through another confusing "MIcrosoft Open" ? program).

Maybe someone can explain this to me or point me in the right direction? My head hurts from going through page after page and not finding a definitive answer, a real pricing sheet, or any tangible set of information. All I get is marketing speak. Ugh.

Comment: What about SQL Server Express? Do you have some requirements that doesn't fit in this edition?

Comment: Yes, the 1 GB RAM limit is definitely not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have to do anything special in
>   order to get SPLA access?

Be a service provider and provide hosted services.

> let's say I have a few web
>   applications that I developed and I
>   want to put those on a server and
>   charge people monthly to use them, is
>   that scenario SPLA covered?

if people pay for ACCESS TO THE SYSTEM, then yes. if your Application is an online shop and people order goods on it - no (because they dont pay to use the software). Clearly defined in the contract.

> (through another confusing "MIcrosoft
>   Open" ? program).

Nothing confusing in there. Seriously. Compared to other companies programs MS programs are very clear.

> All I get is marketing speak

Are you a business or a wannabe developer? I ask like that because I run a business and when I contacted a reseller (SPLA is handled by a number of resellers, one per region, who do the administration) I got down to contracts, price sheets etc. within 24 hours. A lonely developer without even business registration may have a problem here. Rightly so, because you can not be a service provider without being a business.

Just cut through the website, contact someone and get the information. Contact info is on the website. I have no idea where you are, but in EMEA it is INSIGHT which is handling SPLA accounting and reporting.

> I really like SQL Server and I'd love
>   to have a full Web Edition license for
>   $25/mo - much better than the $3,000+
>   license when you buy it outright

What is a better car? A Porsche or a Hummer?

The 3000 USD license is not for the web edition, and the web edition has it's ownlimitations. Please be accurate enough in your own homework to compare features, not only a price tag.

Comment: Could you please clarify the "access to the system" part? Does this mean access to SQL Server directly (e.g. through SQL Server Mgmt Studio), or they pay for access to a web application that uses SQL server (transparent to the user)? I'm simply looking for the least burdening way to get a capable SQL version up and running as a backend for my web apps - maybe there is another option I'm not aware of? Regarding the $3,000 license, that's the online price I get for a 1-Proc SQL Server 2008 Web Edition 'Open' version. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 1):

What I did: I looked for a Microsoft SPLA distributor and signed the contract with them. The distributor would give you an URL of their own for reporting your month use and bill.